# Syntax for table formulation

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to formulate the table with the contents shown. Can someone please help me out with the code.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

An option in tabu environment, using parbox to insert the itemize environment in a multirow cell; to increase the height for the last row i use `...\\[2\baselineskip]`, then to control the position of the item list I use the value of cells in `...\multirrow{Vertical_shift}{*}{...` that only controls the displacement of the text vertically from the cell is declared; finally to control items horizontal position  I use the option `leftmargin` from `itemize` environment.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \sffamily
        \scriptsize
        \def\TableLineSize{1pt}
        \tabulinesep = 1.5pt
        \tabulinestyle{\TableLineSize black}
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X[1.5mc]|X[0.7mc]|X[1.7mc]|X[0.7mc]|X[2mc]|X[3ml]|X[2.5mc]|}
            \tabucline -
            %Row 1
            \rowfont[c]{\bf\sffamily}
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\makecell{Source File\\ Form}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Target File\\ Form}}
            & Physical Quantity for Mapping
            & Transformation Options Used
            & Algorithm Options Used
            \\ \tabucline -  

            %Row 2
            Tool
            & Format
            & Tool
            & Format
            &% for multirow 2-3 col 5
            &% for multirow 2-3 col 6
            &% for multirow 2-3 col 7
            \\[-\TableLineSize] \tabucline {1-4} 

            %Row 3
            ANSYS CFX   
            & .csv
            & Abaqus Standard
            & .inp
            &\multirow{-1}{*}{Pressure}
            &\multirow{-1.7}{*}{
                \parbox{0.2\textwidth}{
                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=15pt]\itemsep-5pt
                        \item Automatic
                        \item Course
                        \item Fine
                        \item Bounding Box
                    \end{itemize}
                }
            }
            &\multirow{-0.8}{*}{
                \parbox{0.2\textwidth}{
                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=15pt]\itemsep-5pt
                        \item Shape Function
                        \item Nearest
                    \end{itemize}
                }
            }
            \\[2\baselineskip] \tabucline -
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{Multirow with itemize in parbox within Tabu environment}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

- please always show us what you try so far and explain where you are stuck (it seems that your question is follow-up to your previous question ...)
- for starting point is used [J Leon V.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/154390/j-leon-v)  answer
- instead (fragile) `tabu` rather use `tabularx`
- for column headers are used `thead` from `makecell`
- more vertical spaces obtained by the macro `\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`
- for the use of the`itemize` redefine its default style in `tablę`
- to my taste the desired showed form of the table is ugly so i rather suggest how i would design your table

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
  \setcellgapes{2pt}
  \renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\theadgape{}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                    after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                    }
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
    \small
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| *{5}{c|} *{2}{X|} }
      \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\thead{Source File Form}}  &
  \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\thead{Target File Form}}  &
  %
  \multirow{2.4}{*}{\thead{aaa\\b}}       &
  \multirow{2.4}{=}{\thead{a\\b}}         &
  \multirow{2.4}{=}{\thead{a\\b}}            \\
      \cline{1-4}
  Tool & Format & Tool & Format  &   &   &   \\
      \hline
  ANSYS CFX
      & .csv
          & \makecell[tl]{Abaqus Standard}
              & .inp
                  & Pressure
                      & \begin{itemize}
                          \item Automatic
                          \item Course
                          \item Fine
                          \item Bounding Box
                        \end{itemize}
                          & \begin{itemize}
                              \item Shape Function
                              \item Nearest
                            \end{itemize}                         \\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \caption{With \texttt{makecell} and \texttt{multirow} within \texttt{tabularx} environment}
    \label{tab:1}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: @PratheekHb, you now have two answers. select on which the best fit to your expectation and accept them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) and up vote them when you will have enough reputation.